# sklearn 0.14.1 RBM dies on NaN or Inf where there is none

Tags: python, scikit-learn, rbm

I'm borrowing an idea [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_rbm_logistic_classification.html#example-plot-rbm-logistic-classification-py) from the documentation to use RBMs + Logistic regression for classification.

However I'm getting an error that should not be thrown since all entries in my data matrix are numerical.

Code:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
from sklearn.neural_network import BernoulliRBM
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets, metrics
import numpy as np

# create fake dataset
data, labels = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=250000)
data = preprocessing.scale(data)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.7, random_state=0)

# print details
print X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape
print np.max(X_train) 
print np.min(X_train)
print np.mean(X_train, axis=0)
print np.std(X_train, axis=0)

if np.sum(np.isnan(X_train)) or np.sum(np.isnan(X_test)):
    print "NaN found!"

if np.sum(np.isnan(y_train)) or np.sum(np.isnan(y_test)):
    print "NaN found!"

if np.sum(np.isinf(X_train)) or np.sum(np.isinf(X_test)):
    print "Inf found!"

if np.sum(np.isinf(y_train)) or np.sum(np.isinf(y_test)):
    print "Inf found!"  

# train and test
logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
rbm = BernoulliRBM(random_state=0, verbose=True)
classifier = Pipeline(steps=[('rbm', rbm), ('logistic', logistic)])

# Training RBM-Logistic Pipeline
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Training Logistic regression
logistic_classifier = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=100.0)
logistic_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Logistic regression using RBM features:\n%s\n" % (
    metrics.classification_report(
        y_test,
        classifier.predict(X_test))))
```

Ouput:

```
(73517, 3) (171540, 3) (73517,) (171540,)
2.0871168057
-2.21062647188
[-0.00237028 -0.00104526  0.00330683]
[ 0.99907225  0.99977328  1.00225843]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/test.py in <module>()
     75 
     76 # Training RBM-Logistic Pipeline

---> 77 classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
     78 
     79 # Training Logistic regression


/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    128         data, then fit the transformed data using the final estimator.
    129         """
--> 130         Xt, fit_params = self._pre_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    131         self.steps[-1][-1].fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    132         return self

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in _pre_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    118         for name, transform in self.steps[:-1]:
    119             if hasattr(transform, "fit_transform"):
--> 120                 Xt = transform.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name])
    121             else:
    122                 Xt = transform.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name]) \

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.pyc in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    409         else:
    410             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

--> 411             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    412 
    413 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neural_network/rbm.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    304 
    305             for batch_slice in batch_slices:
--> 306                 pl_batch = self._fit(X[batch_slice], rng)
    307 
    308                 if verbose:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neural_network/rbm.pyc in _fit(self, v_pos, rng)
    245 
    246         if self.verbose:
--> 247             return self.score_samples(v_pos)
    248 
    249     def score_samples(self, v):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neural_network/rbm.pyc in score_samples(self, v)
    268         fe_ = self._free_energy(v_)
    269 
--> 270         return v.shape[1] * logistic_sigmoid(fe_ - fe, log=True)
    271 
    272     def fit(self, X, y=None):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.pyc in logistic_sigmoid(X, log, out)
    498     """
    499     is_1d = X.ndim == 1
--> 500     X = array2d(X, dtype=np.float)
    501 
    502     n_samples, n_features = X.shape

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in array2d(X, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite)
     91     X_2d = np.asarray(np.atleast_2d(X), dtype=dtype, order=order)
     92     if force_all_finite:
---> 93         _assert_all_finite(X_2d)
     94     if X is X_2d and copy:
     95         X_2d = safe_copy(X_2d)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in _assert_all_finite(X)
     25     if (X.dtype.char in np.typecodes['AllFloat'] and not np.isfinite(X.sum())
     26             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
---> 27         raise ValueError("Array contains NaN or infinity.")
     28 
     29 

ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity.
```

There are no infs or nans in the data matrix...what could be causing this behaviour?

EDIT: Apparently I'm [not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849281/problems-while-using-scikitlearns-neural-network-implementation).

Comment: I think the problem is with the verbosity. I receive a similar error when setting the verbose parameter to a truthy value, but it goes away if I unset it. So as long as you don't need the details about the progress of the training process, you might get by.

Comment: you are correct, it does work under verbose=False. that is strange.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is usually caused by two factors. Incorrect initial scaling of the data. Firstly the input data needs to be bound between 0 and 1. Remember RBM's were originally designed for binary data only.  Secondly the learning rates could be too high. Defaults for RBM code are often based on the MNIST digit recognition dataset which can handle larger learning rates.

So I would trust sklearn's implementation, but not the stability of the algorithm for a new dataset based on default values that don't fit with the current dataset. Adding checks for infinity wont help you will still need to tweak the learning rates.

This is why deep learning is said to be a bit of art, you probably also need to play around with the number of gibs samples, size of minibatch and amount of momentum. Dont give up though, the rewards are mostly worth it. [Further reading](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/guideTR.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a numerical stability bug in RBMs. Can you please open a [github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues) with your script in it?

**Edit**: by the way if you are interested you can try to find the source of the issue by adding `np.isfinite()` checks in the inner loops of the `_fit` method of the `BernoulliRBM` class.

Comment: has this problem been solved in the current version of sklearn?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but this might have been fixed in 0.15+: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2785